# Is there an online database for the endgame KRPPKRP?

Tags: endgame, database, tablebases, rook-endgame

It was stated at this forum that the 7-men-endgames are still not available online.

What about the special endgame KRPPKRP (Rook and 2 pawns against Rook and 1 pawn) ?

It would be nice if the database covers also DTC or DTZ, ideally both.

Answer (score 6):

All of the Syzygy tablebases are available here: https://syzygy-tables.info/

These cover all endgames up to 7-man, and provide WDL (win-draw-loss) and DTZ (distance to zeroing move) data.  Syzygy also distinguishes between a theoretical win or loss that can actually be forced into a draw by the 50-move rule, and one that cannot.

[Here's an example for KRPPvKRP.](https://syzygy-tables.info/?fen=r3k3/4p3/8/8/8/8/3PP3/4K2R_w_-_-_0_1)

Answer (score 5):

There exists a 7-men-endgames tablebase available online, the "Lomonosov endgame tablebase".
see : http://chessok.com/?page_id=27966

Unfortunately, it is not free yet.

Answer (score 4):

The 7-men databases from Lomonosov are available for free via their [Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.convekta.android.lomonosovtb&hl=en).

[image]

I've analyzed the traffic between the app and server a while ago, and discovered that it's easy to 'fake' your own calls to the server, so you're not depending on having an Android device nearby anymore. IIRC it worked with FEN strings. I don't have the specifics anymore, and it's probably against the Terms of Service of the app.

Comment: Just checked, it's still working for me ...